# Azure edge hub message expiry not triggering callback

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I have a scenario where I need to display a message if a module is unresponsive for more than a few seconds.

To do this, I call `sendEventAsync` where I construct a message with an expiry time of 2000ms:

```java
module.sendMessageToTopic(ConnectionStatusRequest.newBuilder().withExpiryTime(2000).build(), (responseStatus, callbackContext) -> {
    if (IotHubStatusCode.MESSAGE_EXPIRED.equals(responseStatus)) {
        LOGGER.warn("Could not retrieve connection status before TTL, considering module as offline.");
        broadcastConnectionStatus(IotHubConnectionStatus.DISCONNECTED);
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Received status callback for connection status: {}", responseStatus);
    }
});
```

The edge deployment schema has a TTL of 90 seconds for all routes except upstream, and I want this specific message to exist for 2 seconds. If I have not received a response on this topic within 2 seconds, I consider the message expired  and the module in question is considered offline. I've also tried setting a route specific TTL of 2 seconds with no expiry time set on the message, but I get the same result.

However, when I try to force the issue by manually killing the container that listens on this topic, and it takes > 2 seconds for it to start again, I never get a callback with status `MESSAGE_EXPIRED`:

```
2021-07-19 09:25:42,683 [WebSocketWorker-17] INFO  s.i.l.w.service.WebSocketService.broadcastConnectionStatus(470) - Module is online, requesting additional status information from other modules.
2021-07-19 09:25:42,740 [azure-iot-sdk-IotHubSendTask] INFO  s.i.l.w.service.WebSocketService.lambda$broadcastConnectionStatus$32(476) - Received status callback for connection status: OK_EMPTY
```

When I dig through the source code of the module logic for Java, it seems like it should poll for messages to send and receive every 10ms. It then invokes whatever callback was provided with that message. A message is considered expired when `System.currentTimeMillis()` is greater than the provided expiry time. That should set the packet status to `MESSAGE_EXPIRED` and add it to a callback queue that is invoked on an executor schedule.

So what I would expect is:

1. `OK_EMPTY` when Edge Hub has received the message
2. `MESSAGE_EXPIRED` on the same callback when Edge Hub fails to get an ack within 2 seconds on the topics consumer

Am I misunderstanding how these callbacks work?

How does the programmatic setter for expiry time on the `Message` object relate to the TTL of the edge hub routes?

Where can I listen to the `MESSAGE_EXPIRED` event to achieve my desired behavior?

Update:

I tried turning expiry time down to 0, and that immediately triggers a `MESSAGE_EXPIRED` even when the module I sent to is online. I've tried trimming the time down from 500 ms to 100 ms in 100 ms increments, but it doesn't help; I still don't get the `MESSAGE_EXPIRED` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `setExpiryTime` method on a message that is sent to the edge hub, that expiry is only valid if the sender fails to deliver to message to the edge hub.

Once the message is delivered to the edge hub, the SDKs job is completed and it is a "fire and forget".

Once on the edge hub, you can use `timeToLiveSecs` in the routes section. However that doesn't cause any callback either, it simply tells the edge hub to discard messages that fail to be delivered within the time limit.